# How to add additional .ui files in Qt VS Add-in

Tags: user-interface, visual-studio-2013, qt5, qt-vs-addin

I have created a Qt Application project in Visual Studio. It generates one .ui file for the main window. What if I want to add another window?

Answer (score 3):

If you use visual studio 2013 and Qt 5, right click your project in solution explorer and select **Add -> Class...** to launch **Add Class** dialog.

You can create **Qt5GuiClass** for your new window in the dialog.

Answer (score 1):

From the **Solution Explorer** of you Visual studio, right click on the **Form files** -> **Add new Item** -> **Qt forms** from there select *Qt Dialog form (.ui)*

Comment: And what is `Form files -> Add new Item -> Qt forms` doesn't exist?